# Google Map geocode to latlng

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geocode

I am trying to get  the latitude and longitude of the marker from this geocode.. this may seem really simple for you guys. I'm sorry, i've tried a lot of things like addListener but nothing seems to work. please help :(

```
    function codeAddress() {
      var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
      geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
      } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have some problems too with the geocoder.
This code works fine with addresses, that contain no special characters:

```
var addr="YOUR ADDRES";  
 var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
     geocoder.geocode({address: addr, region: 'ar'}, function(results, status) {
     if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
     var GeoPos=results[0].geometry.location;
                                                 }
                                                                             });
```

Check the region parameter in the geocode function. I'm Using `ar`, because I from Argentina.

Comment: actually, what i need is to get the latitude and longitude of the geocode and display it into a textbox

Comment: thanks nosoul for your suggestion.. i was able to find a way to extract and display the coordinates of my geocode, but not in a text box.. please refer to the answer i posted below.

Answer (score 0):

here's a code that i was able to use to display the latitude and longitude into my website when searching using geocode... it displays into a  and not a textbox though, and when I think about it, it's actually better.

```
var searchlat = new Number(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
var searchlng = new Number(results[0].geometry.location.lng());
document.getElementById('sethomelat').innerHTML=searchlat.toFixed(8)
document.getElementById('sethomelng').innerHTML=searchlng.toFixed(8)
```

.toFixed() lets me specify the exact number of decimal places that will show up.

hope this can help others who have the same problem. :D